# Display modal (only 1 time) after first login with Ruby on Rails + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to show an introduction modal to new user after the first sign in.

```
  <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.sign_in_count == 1 %>
      <%= render 'introduction_slides' %>
  <% end %>
```

The sign_in_count works great. but the problem is that user needs to signout and in to stop seeing that modal. Is there any better way to make this happen? Maybe using Cookie?

Comment: after rendering, **introduction_slides** 
change the value ```current_user.sign_in_count``` to something else.

It would be better if you could share the code in the sandbox

Answer (score -1):

I figured out with **Session**

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.sign_in_count == 1 %>
  <% unless session[:introduction_slides] %>
    <%= render 'introduction_slides' %>
    <% session[:introduction_slides] = true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```